# Are the hoor gair aaqil?

Tags: arabic, jannah

In Arabic, humans, jinn and angels are considered "*aaqil*" ("عاقل"), meaning they are sentient or thinking beings. Everything else is considered "*gair aaqil*" ("غير عاقل").

So the question is, are the hoor in jannah considered *aaqil*, or *gair aaqil*?

Comment: This question is about Arabic language and this site is about Islam: off-topic.